# "Unwrapping" an extended partition

Tags: partitioning

My current computer came with one small primary partition, and one large extended partition with many smaller partitions inside:

```
+-------+-------------+
|       |  Secondary  |
|Primary+----+---+-----
|       |  A | B | C  |
+-------+----+---+----+
```

This layout is rather uncomfortable, and I'm trying to get rid of the secondary partition. Is there some way to "unwrap" it in one step, rather than moving data out of it and shrinking it until I can delete it?

Comment: What is "uncomfortable" about the current setup? What **problem** are you actually trying to solve? Edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted so that I can make a better recommendation.

Comment: @heynnema I already solved the problem by copying files around, sorry. Anyway, what was uncomfortable was that I wanted to have one large ext4 partition (for my OS) and one small swap partition, but the fact that the extended partition took most of the space and that my OS was outside of it made it uncomfortable - I would have had to copy the OS into the extended partition, resize it, and convert the remaining space to swap.

Comment: Remember that the "secondary" or extended partition is just a wrapper around logical partitions A-C, and that is mostly used in MBR partition tables, where there's a maximum of four partitions possible. If you'd like to post a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, I can comment more. You have a current swap partition, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, there are at least two ways to do this:

- **Convert to GPT** -- The newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) supports up to 128 partitions by default (and that value can be raised, if necessary), with no distinction between primary, extended, and logical partitions. Some tools, including my own GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, `cgdisk`), which comes with Ubuntu in the `gdisk` package, can convert from the older Master Boot Record (MBR; which you're using) to GPT; see [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) for details. Note, however, that this change will require re-installing your boot loader. If your computer is new (late 2011 or later), switching from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting may be desirable if you make this change. Either way, you'll probably have to create a new partition (a ~550MiB ESP for EFI-mode or a smaller ~1MiB BIOS Boot Partition for BIOS-mode). Also, if you're dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows, switching from MBR to GPT becomes much more complex, since then you'll need to update both OSes' boot loaders, and Windows does not support booting from GPT disks in BIOS mode, so this change will work only if your computer supports EFI-mode booting. (See [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170306032145/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) for information on converting Windows from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting.)
- **Convert from logical to primary** -- Some tools, such as my [FixParts (`fixparts`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/), can convert partitions from logical to primary form. (Note that `fixparts` is also provided by the Ubuntu `gdisk` package.) There are caveats, though. If you have more than four primary plus logical partitions, you'll be able to have a total of no more than three primary partitions, so you might not be able to convert all your partitions. Depending on what partitions are involved in booting, what OSes you have installed, etc., you may need to adjust your boot loader configuration(s) after the conversion. As a general rule, converting from logical to primary isn't worthwhile, IMHO; although the extended partition is an awkward (albeit long-lived) hack, it doesn't really make it impossible to do things that would be possible if you had nothing but primary partitions; it just adds an extra step or two. (A notable exception is if you're installing an OS that requires a primary partition -- but then conventional partitioning tools can usually do the job.)

Note that both of these paths carry risks. The actual partition conversions involve relatively simple calculations and few writes of data, but there's always the possibility that a bug or random I/O error might cause disastrous data loss, given the critical nature of partition table data structures. As noted, you may also need to update or re-install your boot loader after making the change, and if you have problems with this step, the process will be a nightmare.

If you consider the extended/logical partitions to be awkward because you're making frequent partition changes, I recommend you look into using a [Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) configuration. LVM is a sort of advanced pseudo-partition setup that runs atop regular partitions. It's more flexible because the logical volumes (partition equivalents) in LVM are treated like files; they can be created and resized without worrying about their physical locations on the disk. Converting from a regular partition scheme to LVM can be awkward, though. The best way is normally to back up, create a fresh LVM setup, and restore (or re-install and then restore your user data). The [`blocks`](https://github.com/g2p/blocks) tool claims to be able to do this in place, but I've never tried it, so I can't comment on its safety, reliability, or ease of use, except to say that the description in the README says that a filesystem resize is part of the operation, which creates some inherent danger. Note also that, depending on what you convert, you're likely to end up needing to re-install your boot loader, or at least tweak its configuration, after doing the conversion.